# Apache Flink: No output when using event time with multiple Kafka partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading messages from a Kafka topic with 2 partitions and using event time. This is my code:

```java
stream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Request>() {
    @Override
    public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Request req) {
        return req.ts;
    }
})
.windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1)))
.apply((TimeWindow window, Iterable<Request> iterable, Collector<String> collector) -> {
    collector.collect("Window: " + window.toString());
    for (Request req : iterable) {
        collector.collect(req.toString());
    }
})
.print()
```

I could get an output only when setting the Kafka source parallelism to 1. According to [this thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Kafka-partition-alignment-for-event-time-td4782.html#a4804), I guess that is because messages from multiple partitions arrive out-of-order to the timestamp extractor.

So I replaced the `AscendingTimestampExtractor` with a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator` as in [this documentation example](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#tab_java_3) (with a higher maxOutOfOrderness delay), in order to handle out-of-order events, but I still can't get any output. Why is that?

Comment: How much data do you ingest (ie, over what event time period)? Keep in mind, that the first output will be produced after your 1-day time window gets closed, and this happens if the first watermark that is larger than "one day" arrives.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasJ.Sax, sorry for the late response. The data I'm ingesting is over 1 year period, I'm actually aggregating historic data in a streaming fashion. It turns out the problem is that one of the topic partitions is empty, thus the watermark does not advance for it.
I could fix it by setting topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms in the producer config.
[Here](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/No-output-when-using-event-time-with-multiple-Kafka-partitions-td8132.html) is the related mailing list thread.

Comment: I am also facing same problem in my flink application. I have created 4 partitions with parallelism 4 and I am getting out of order data. I have used BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator with delay of 3 seconds. Is there any way to achieve order in streaming based on event time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the event timestamp is OK. Must have a 13 length to be used in Flink Java Epoch.

**Correct**: 1563743505673

**Incorrect**: 1563743505

Ref.: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#assigning-timestamps